# Android Get Device's Keys List

Tags: java, android, button, hardware

Is it possible to get the device's keys and to use them?
For example the combination of the volume keys to create a shortcut?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Key Events](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) should be what you are looking for.